# Android SQLite getting records from one table based on another

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

Please excuse me if its a repeated question. I tried searching here and at google but I couldn't exactly find what I wanted.

I have got two tables A & B. 
Table A Fields : id, name, description, rating.
Table B Fields : id, aId (linked to table A), customerId, recommended.

Table A contains my data items for which I'm storing average cumulative ratings provided by users.
Table B stores another attribute for data of Table A. It stores the recommended bit (1 for recommended & 0 for non-recommended).

I want to list all the data from Table A but I want to sort them using recommended bit from Table B. So, if there are 10 records in Table A and 2 records in Table B, while listing all those 10 records, the two from Table B should come first and then the others from Table A. It doesn't matter whether the recommended bit value is a 0 or a 1. While listing the other 8 records from Table A, I want to list the records based on their rating in descending order.

Can someone please guide me in writing this sqlite query for Android app? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The left join adds the `recommended` field to the result set (with a value of `NULL` if there is no matching `B` record).
The expression `recommended IS NULL` or `EXISTS(...)` returns either 0 or 1:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.*
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.id = B.aId
ORDER BY B.recommended IS NULL,
         A.rating DESC
```

Alternatively:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
ORDER BY NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                     FROM B
                     WHERE B.aId = A.id),
         rating DESC
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. However, it doesn't work completely. It gives me duplicate records from Table A and field id from Table A is also not correct in all of those records. Is there any way where we can remove duplicate records from showing up? Thanks